# How to deploy minimal ASP.NET/Razor WebApp with Github Workflow using VS 2022 CI/CD feature to generate YAML?

Tags: visual-studio, github-actions

**Background**:

I'm trying to use that Visual Studio (2022) CI/CD feature (part of the publish feature) that automatically generates the workflow YAML file in the .github/workflows directory.

When I trigger the workflow with a push, I always get this same error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I clearly have a .csproj file that is being committed and checked in... You can see it in my git hub repo.

**What I have tried:**

I've been following these [directions that make no mention have having to edit the YAML file](https://dailydotnettips.com/ci-cd-using-github-actions-workflow-directly-from-visual-studio/).

As can bee seen here [.github/workflows/xyfolxgnipoogweb.yml](https://github.com/siegfried01/DemoVisualStudioCICDForASPNETRazor/commit/456e9739c6aa011e51cbbc89918bbc27c5533944) and [here](https://github.com/siegfried01/DemoVisualStudioCICDForASPNETRazor/commit/77971e1c907b994f99a853ba3ea67ce9dc3d2196) and [again here](https://github.com/siegfried01/DemoVisualStudioCICDForASPNETRazor/commit/81f93cd42807c23e015e6712ef122b88521ca3fe)) I've been trying to guide it to my project files as per [this Microsoft example that demonstrates the `paths: '**.csproj'` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/devops/dotnet-build-github-action) and github copilot suggestions and bing/google searching... Nothing works (so far).

Is it necessary to edit this YAML file generated by Visual Studio? If not, what could be wrong?

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: I had originally thought that the path clause would tell the runner where the csproj file was. Apparently this is not so: it is for specifying which file changes can trigger a build.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
I had some trouble with the repository linked in the original problem statement above and I have since created another github repo (again)...

**Problem: Wrong Directory!**

Visual Studio 2022 generates this code:

```
env:
...
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: .
jobs:
```

**Resolution: Specify the child directory where the source code is!**

The above code is incorrect and it necessary to manually edit the file specify the correct directory:

```
env:
...
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: ./DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer
jobs:
```

**Diagnosing the Problem:**

Adding this diagnostic code helped identify the problem:

```
    - name: Where are we
      run: echo "Hello from $PWD"
```

I hope this will help someone else someday.